# Alter postgres table primary key UUID to Character Varying

Tags: postgresql

I want to convert my PostgreSQL table primary key UUID to character varying

```
ALTER TABLE payment_authorization ALTER COLUMN id TYPE VARCHAR;
```

When I run the above command showing below error, Beacause foreign key constraints failed. In my system have 200 tables. Is there any easy way to change all tables primary key?

Comment: Maybe dump/edit/restore would be easier than lots of `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: can you give me an example.

Comment: I can hardly give you an example... What I mean is `pg_dump -Fp` the database, use your favorite text editor to replace `uuid` with `character varying` in the `CREATE TABLE` statements, `DROP DATABASE` and then load the edited dump.

Comment: Do you need to migrate all uuid primary keys (+ foreign keys) or just one (+ foreign keys)?

Comment: I want to migrate all the uuid primary and foreign keys

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you're correct. I just export to .sql file and changes the data type reimport the db. it works. Thaks a lot. Maybe you can post as an answer, so I can accept as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing all the tables in place will probably be slow and cumbersome.

The easiest solution might be:

- export the database with

  ```bash
  pg_dump -F p -f dumpfile.sql dbname
  ```
- replace `uuid` with `text` in the dump using an editor:

  ```bash
  sed --in-place -e 's/uuid/text/g' dumpfile.sql
  ```
- drop and re-create the database:

  ```
  DROP DATABASE dbname;
  CREATE DATABASE dbname;
  ```
- import the dump:

  ```
  psql -U postgres -d dbname -1 -f dumpfile.sql
  ```